# Asp.net Progressbar in pop up window

Tags: asp.net, popup, progress-bar

I want to show **progrssbar** in pop up windows. 
I refere [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/guillermo/archive/2008/02/24/ajax-how-to-create-a-quot-processing-quot-modal-window-using-updateprogress-and-modalpopup-asp-net-ajax-controls.aspx) site for showing progress bar in pop up window. I am importing contact from Gmail,Yahoo,Hotmail. When I import my contact and select contact and click on Invite button my pop up window displays. But the problem is that my progress bar i.e. **loading.gif** is not circulating.
Can anyone tell me why I am getting this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an update panel ?, because it works only in case of update panel.